# Passing data between Rails view and Vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am trying to simply pass an instance variable from my rails view to a Vue.js component. The error message I am getting is:

```
Property or method "epic_list" is not defined on the instance
but referenced during render.
```

Here is my code:

Vue.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';
import Roadmap from '../components/Roadmap.vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

Vue.component('roadmap', Roadmap);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const element = document.getElementById('roadmap');
  const epics = element.dataset.epics
  console.log(epics);
  const app = new Vue({
    el: element,
    template: '<Roadmap :epic_list="epics"/>',
    components: { Roadmap }
  });
  console.log(app);
});
```

Component:

```
<template>
    <div id="roadmap">
        <div v-for="(epic, key) in epic_list">
          {{ epic.name }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      epic_list: Object
    },
  }
</script>
```

Rails view:

```
div data-behavior='vue'
    = tag.div id: :roadmap, data: {epics: @project_epics.to_json}
```

This seems like a really simple thing, as I read in this stack overflow question: [Pass data from Rails views to VueJS components in webpacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821728/pass-data-from-rails-views-to-vuejs-components-in-webpacker), but I continually get the "epic_list" is not defined, even though it prints correctly to the console every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `console.log(epics);` show in the console?

Comment: it prints an array of my objects, like: [{id: 1, title: "test"}, {id: 2, title: "testing"}], as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `console.log(epics);` is already printing a value in the console, then can you try the following?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const element = document.getElementById('roadmap');
  const epics = element.dataset.epics
  console.log(epics);
  const app = new Vue({
    el: element,
    template: '<Roadmap :epics_list="epics"/>',
    // added these lines:
    data: {
      epics: epics
    },
    components: { Roadmap }
  });
  console.log(app);
});
```

Comment: it's a miracle 

Comment: Good to hear! :) Glad to help!